# Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions: com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, migration, issue-tracking, safetynet

When I want to upload my flutter aab in Play Console, I got the below warning.

> Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions:
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0

What the SDK developer told us:

> The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

Kindly help me resolve that. The app is made in flutter.

Comment: What is your exact issue? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @JamesZ What can I do so that the warning get resolved???

Comment: Well they are obviously telling you to use the new API. Again, are you not reading it, are you just leaving out important information or what? Still totally impossible to figure out what you're asking

Comment: will the app be published even if I get this warning. Review is taking too long.

Comment: I've been in the review for a closed test for about 3 days! really boring @kragekjaer

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using safety net anywhere just do the below changes in your code.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth') {
        exclude module: "play-services-safetynet"
    }
```

Comment: this is not working, still same issue

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me, Playstore complains about SDK critical issue.
I was using **firebase_auth** on top of **google sign in** in my flutter application, and **firebase_auth** has `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0` as its dependency.

You can check what package is dependent on **safetynet** by running **gradlew** command. Navigate to android folder within your flutter project and run `./gradlew app:dependencies`

So I removed **firebase_auth** and use only **google sign in**, now all good with Playstore. My application is flexible and does not `require` safety/verification nor firebase auth, hence I am ok to remove the firebase part for now. You can do similar troubleshooting and identify package dependent on safetynet and decide. Hope this helps your case too.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered in a similar question here, you need to update com.google.gms:google-services because it contains safetyNet API.
Use ver 4.3.13 and the warning has gone.

[Play Store Warning : play-services-safetynet (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) has reported critical issues with version 17.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028990/play-store-warning-play-services-safetynet-com-google-android-gmsplay-servic/73047452#73047452)